# How to write a Scala Argonaut codec for all Java enums

Tags: scala, argonaut

I have a Scala project that uses a bunch of Java code, for example this Java source:

```
public enum Category { FOO, BAR };
```

I then have a bunch of Scala case classes that I serialise to and from JSON using Argonaut like this:

```
case class Thing (a: String, b: Int, c: Float)
object Thing {
  implicit val j = casecodec3 (Thing.apply, Thing.unapply)("a", "b", "c")
  implicit val e: Equal[Guild] = Equal.equal (_ == _)
}
```

Fine, now I want to write a Scala case class that uses a Java enum like so:

```
case class Thing (a: String, b: Int, c: Float, d: Category)
object Thing {
  implicit val j = casecodec4 (Thing.apply, Thing.unapply)("a", "b", "c", "d")
  implicit val e: Equal[Guild] = Equal.equal (_ == _)
}
```

This will yield a compilation error because there is no implicit codec for the Category enum.

I guess I could write my own codec specifically for dealing with the Category enum by doing something like this:

```
package object ArgonautImplicits {
  implicit val dx: DecodeJson[Category] = StringDecodeJson.map(x => Category.valueOf(x))
  implicit val ex: EncodeJson[Category] = EncodeJson(x => jString(x.toString))
}
```

But I want to know if there is a way to write a single codec that will automatically handle any Java enum.